# #include "glm/ext.hpp" makes the compiler report a __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glm-math

I get the compiler error `__declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned`.

When I click the error, Visual Studio sends me to `GLM_IMPLEMENT_SCAL_MULT(vec4)`, which is on the scalar_multiplication.hpp file.

What is the cause for this compiler error? How can I fix it?

---

Note: Could it be some kind of conflict with the includes? I have several includes in a header file. The commented one is the one that gives the error.

```
// OpenGL Math library
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
//#include "glm/ext.hpp" // For printing matrices

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

Comment: Weird, searching for `__declspec align won't be aligned` gave me plenty of results.

Comment: I mean searching both the include and the error. I also see more links if I remove some characters from the include but I can't find useful links :(

Comment: What's on the line generating this warning?

Comment: I'm also getting this since updating to the latest GLM.  I was using 0.9.4.6 before but the slerp function had a killer bug.  I'm using VS2013.  It's loads of c2719 errors found in the scalar_multiplication.hpp header of GLM.  It's also gviing other warnings throughout the program where I instantiate objects:  object allocated on the heap may not be aligned 16 (c4316).

Comment: Yes. this is unfortunate but malloc has no alignment spec. most of the time the alignment is hardcoded to 16 so this should be OK here. another point of problem is by-value-parameter-passing where its impossible to guarantee alignment, especially with visual studio which is weaker than other compilers on this domain,

Comment: This line where Visual Studio sends me when I click the error
`GLM_IMPLEMENT_SCAL_MULT(vec4)`, @Jerem (It is on the scalar_multiplication.hpp file)