# Ambiguous call on glm::slerp

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

The error is (using VS2013 - GLM):

> more than one instance of overloaded function "glm::slerp" matches the
>   argument list: function template "glm::detail::tquat
>   glm::slerp(const glm::detail::tquat &x, const glm::detail::tquat
>   &y, const T &a)" function template "T glm::slerp(const
>   glm::detail::tquat &x, const glm::detail::tquat &y, const T &a)"
>   argument types are: (glm::quat, glm::quat, float)

I'm calling it with two glm::quat and a constant float value, just like you would do with glm::lerp and glm::mix. The two overloaded functions shown in the error message only differs on the return type. I've been searching for an answer without any luck.

The exact call:

```
const float t = 0.5f;
glm::quat newQ = glm::slerp(quatA, quatB, t);
```

Comment: I don't suppose VS2013 points you to the in-file declarations that the error refers to?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible (hear illegal) in C++ to have function definitions that differs only by return type because the return type is not part of the signature, and therefore will violate one definition rule.

I suggest you write the template parameters explicitely, or cast to something you are sure ?

Comment: That's the reason I'm posting this because it makes no sense - the signature is based on the parameters.  However, this is the error message I'm getting and yes, I have tried casting but without any luck.

Comment: Maybe the 2 functions with the same signature that you found, do not exist in the same namespace. This is a typical `gml` design technique where implementations are in `detail` namespaces and they are brought to `glm` namespace by `using` directives according to includes or defines to bring features in, in a configurable manner.

Comment: I updated GLM to their latest version, and can now use the slerp function without it turning red (I missed the December updates).  Sadly, I have run into another problem which somebody else is having (I left a comment): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023412/include-glm-ext-hpp-makes-the-compiler-report-a-declspecalign16-wont

Comment: I'm going to stick with version 0.9.5.4 which compiles fine.  6.x versions seem to have a few wrinkles to iron out so I will wait for it to be updated.  This version won't compile with slerp (same problem) but now it's even less informative as it doesn't turn red (just a c2668 during compile).  I think I will just write my own slerp function for now, or stick with glm::mix and work on something else until GLM updates.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: How about submitting something about that fact here : https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues don't forget to mention this page as a link

Comment: Actually there is somethind about that already it seems: https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/286

Comment: Sadly, the fix is in the 0.9.6.0 version, which has the same problem as the 0.9.6.1 version does (align 16) as previously mentioned.  I may submit that instead.